# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

Tags: php, laravel

The problem that I'm having in my web app is that when a user types up a status and presses "add status" instead of it saving the status I get the following error : `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)`.
I have done some research online and looked at similar problems and tried changing it around but I still got the same problem back .

This is my Controller Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $r)
    {
        if(Request::has('status-text'))
        {
            $text = e(Request::get('status-text'));

            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus->status_text = $text;
            $userStatus->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus->save();
            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('home'));

                }


        return view('home');
    }
}
```

This is my web.php class

```
<?php
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::any('/home', ['as'=> 'home','uses'=>'HomeController@index']);
```

[image]

This is an image of the error that I'm getting back :

[image]

Comment: You're visiting a page that doesn't exist. It's a 404

Comment: I know it doesn't ,it just supposed to save the status first and then go back to the home page

Comment: What does the URL in the browser say after you save the status (and get 404)?

Comment: http://social.com/foo/bar

Comment: See - this url doesn't exist in your routes. What's the logic that gets you to this url? "The problem that I'm having in my web app is that when a user types up a status and presses "add status" " - Show the code how that happens.

Comment: When the user enters the data and presses "add status" ,they are supposed to be redirected back to the home page : `return redirect(route('home'));` ,but I get that URL instead ,I don't know why I'm get getting  social.com/foo/bar

Comment: it doesn't exists because he returns view('welcome') at the top of the web file

Comment: @devk You were right about `/foo/bar` ,I had to change the URL in home.blade.php from `foo/bar` to `home` and now it works ,it saves the posts of the users

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you can just have return view() in the routes/web.php file. All you should need to do is make your web.php like this:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home','HomeController@index');
```

that should fix your problem.

Comment: That didn't change anything ,still getting the same error

Comment: Yes here you're just narrowing the scope of which requests are accepted. From `any` to `GET` only.

Comment: did you remove     return view('welcome');}); from your web.php file? That was the most important part!!

Comment: @AlexMac Yes I tried without `return view('welcome');});` and got the same result back

Comment: are you getting redirected because you do not have a logged in user?

Comment: No ,the user is logged in ,they are redirected the same page ,they write the status on the home page and get redirect to the same page